# How to Debug locally with Android Studio the Google Play Billing library on App that "App Signing by Google Play"?

Tags: android, firebase, in-app-billing, google-play-console, android-app-signing

When I trying to purchase In-app product with Google billing library from my app that currently running locally from android studio on physical device I'm getting this error:
"This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play"
the version name and code of the app are thew same as the version on Google Play Console.
I'm signing the app with the same key that I used in google play console App integrity.
when I'm download the app from the internal testing the purchase is working but when I'm trying to run in release or debug mode from android studio I'm getting this error.
is it not possible to test google billing library when I am using "App Signing by Google Play"?

I try to enter all types of SHA1 to firebase and replace the google-services.json file,
I tryed to sign the app with the same key on release and debug build types (the same key I used to uplaod the app and use to sign by google in the play console).